# Running jar works but running HTML (JNLP) doesn't work properly

Tags: java, html, jar, localhost, jnlp

I'm using Netbeans 8.1, Java 1.8.0-121. I want to write a file to the local system.

If I run a .jar file it works fine.  I get the filename thru fileChooser.
having `<security><all-permissions/></security>` in JNLP doesn't help.

But if I run from HTML (with JNLP) then I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied            
("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\NBP\Tableonly\vsebinaa.xlsx" "write")
```

All jars are properly jarsigned!

What is causing this error?

Comment: *"All jars are properly jarsigned!"* Are they signed using a certificate from a CA?

Comment: I  hope so! Issuer =  CN=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA,
 O="thawte, Inc.", C=US.

Comment: If it was issued by Thawte, then yes they are a CA. How did you check the jars were properly signed? Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: JaNeLA is returning >cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jfx:javafx-desc'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: `jfx:javafx-desc` Oops! I never updated it to include support for Java-FX because there was no DTD that gave the syntax. No other errors?

Comment: I apologize! I used XMLbeans 2.6.2  but I can't sign it. I Replaced it with xmlbeans 5.2.4 and it looks OK!